# Is there a way to export a function used within a BRMS model when parallelising posterior_epred with foreach()?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, brms

I am predicting a BRMS categorical model on a very large set of new data. When I try to predict with the whole dataset, R crashes or it exhausts the vector memory. To get around that, I want to loop through my new data and speed it up using `foreach()`. However, I can't seem to export a function I used to scale the data in my original model, even if I redefine the function in the `foreach()` loop. I'm not sure I totally understand how the function within my BRMS formula is stored in the model, which might be why I'm struggling to export it.

Here's basically what my code looks like:

```
test_data <- data.frame(category=c(rep("a",10),
                                   rep("b",10),
                                   rep("c",10)),
                        var1 = runif(30,min=0,max=20))

scale01 <- function(x) (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))

test_brm <- brm(category ~ scale01(var1),
                family=categorical(refcat="a"),
                data=test_data)

prediction_data <- data.frame(id=rep(c(1:500),2),
                              var1=runif(1000,min=0,max=20))

cl <- makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
registerDoSNOW(cl)

preds <- foreach(id = prediction_data$id,.combine=rbind,
                 packages=c("brms","matrixStats")) %dopar% {
                   
                   scale01 <- function(x) (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
                   
                   colMeans(posterior_epred(test_brm,
                                            newdata=prediction_data[which(prediction_data$id==id),]))
                   
                 }
```

And the error I get is `Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "scale01""`

I'm aware that the scaling function I use relies on having the same max and min each time, but my newdata does (perhaps could hard code that but don't think it's the problem here).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `scale01()` is no longer associated with the formula `category ~ scale01(var1)` when the formula is exported to the parallel worker. This has to do with both of them living the global environment, which is never exported to parallel workers. To work around that, you can make `scale01()` part of the same local environment as the `brmsfit` object, as show below.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(brms)

test_data <- data.frame(category=c(rep("a",10),
                                   rep("b",10),
                                   rep("c",10)),
                        var1 = runif(30,min=0,max=20))

test_brm <- local({
  scale01 <- function(x) (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
  
  brm(category ~ scale01(var1),
      family = categorical(refcat="a"),
      data = test_data)
})                 

prediction_data <- data.frame(
  id = rep(c(1:500), times = 2),
  var1 = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 20)
)

cl <- makeCluster(parallelly::availableCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

preds <- foreach(id = prediction_data$id, .combine = rbind, .packages = c("brms")) %dopar% {
  data <- prediction_data[which(prediction_data$id == id), ]
  colMeans(posterior_epred(test_brm, newdata=data))
}

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Here I replaced **doSNOW** with **doParallel**. You do not want to rely on **doSNOW**, because that depends on the **snow** package, which is considered a legacy package right now. The **parallel** package, part of all R installation, has replaced the role of **snow** since ~2014.

Also, importantly, do not default to `detectCores()`. It can wreak havoc on shared computers. Instead, use `parallelly::availableCores()`.  For details, see https://www.jottr.org/2022/12/05/avoid-detectcores/.

Now, as the author of [Futureverse](https://www.futureverse.org/), I should also point out the following alternative code that achieves the same, while automating a lot of the details for you. It'll also support printing output on parallel workers, proper error handling, etc., which will all help you if you run into other problems.

```
library(foreach)
library(doFuture)
library(brms)

test_data <- data.frame(category=c(rep("a",10),
                                   rep("b",10),
                                   rep("c",10)),
                        var1 = runif(30,min=0,max=20))

test_brm <- local({
  scale01 <- function(x) (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
  
  brm(category ~ scale01(var1),
      family = categorical(refcat="a"),
      data = test_data)
})                 

prediction_data <- data.frame(
  id = rep(c(1:500), times = 2),
  var1 = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 20)
)

plan(multisession)

preds <- foreach(id = prediction_data$id, .combine = rbind) %dofuture% {
  data <- prediction_data[which(prediction_data$id == id), ]
  colMeans(posterior_epred(test_brm, newdata=data))
}

plan(sequential)
```

BTW, instead of subsetting `data` within each iteration, you probably want to set up an "iterator" (see **iterators** package) to do that subsetting in the main R session.  That would avoid sending over the whole `prediction_data` object to each parallel worker, which can be expensive, particularly for data sets.

UPDATE: As an alternative to **foreach** and **iterators**, you can achieve something similar automatically by using `future.apply::future_by()`. If you try that, I recommend by first figuring out how to do it sequentially using `by()` that is part of base R. When that works, `future_by()` should work the same.

Comment: Ah great, solved it - thank you! Your futureverse version is much nicer, and you're right I definitely need an iterator. `future.apply::future_by` is very nice!